# How to make this array work in the parameter list just like the anonymous attributes?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array to send into the constructor of this BarChart. To me it looks like the parameters are anonymous attributes which are assigned to the canvasID, data and so forth. Is there a way to send these into the constructor as an array and have them map their specific fields.

I know that in the constructor each data element is accessed through config.canvasID, and config.data and config.color etc.

Code:

```
                var barvalues = ["myCanvas",data,"yellow",50,0,20,2]
                /*
                new BarChart({
                    canvasId: "myCanvas",
                    data: data,
                    color: "blue",
                    barWidth: 50,
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 20,
                    gridLineIncrement: 2
                });
                */
                new BarChart(barvalues);

Constructor:

function BarChart(config){
                // user defined properties
                this.canvas = document.getElementById(config.canvasId);
                this.data = config.data;
                this.color = config.color;
                this.barWidth = config.barWidth;
                this.gridLineIncrement = config.gridLineIncrement;
                /*
                 * adjust max value to highest possible value divisible
                 * by the grid line increment value and less than
                 * the requested max value
                 */
                this.maxValue = config.maxValue - Math.floor(config.maxValue % this.gridLineIncrement);
                this.minValue = config.minValue;

                // constants
                this.font = "12pt Calibri";
                this.axisColor = "#555";
                this.gridColor = "#aaa";
                this.padding = 10;

                // relationships
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                this.range = this.maxValue - this.minValue;
                this.numGridLines = this.numGridLines = Math.round(this.range / this.gridLineIncrement);
                this.longestValueWidth = this.getLongestValueWidth();
                this.x = this.padding + this.longestValueWidth;
                this.y = this.padding * 2;
                this.width = this.canvas.width - (this.longestValueWidth + this.padding * 2);
                this.height = this.canvas.height - (this.getLabelAreaHeight() + this.padding * 4);

                // draw bar chart
                this.drawGridlines();
                this.drawYAxis();
                this.drawXAxis();
                this.drawBars();
                this.drawYVAlues();
                this.drawXLabels();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

make a little wrapper to invoke it:

```
function myChart(id, data, color, bar, min, max, grid){
  return  new BarChart({
                    canvasId: id,
                    data: data,
                    color: color,
                    barWidth: bar,
                    minValue: min,
                    maxValue: max,
                    gridLineIncrement: grid
                });
}



usage: chart1=myChart("myCanvas",data,"yellow",50,0,20,2)
```

you can use "new " first if you feel like, but it also won't hurt anymore to just call myChart() directly...

Answer (score 0):

This function converts your original array into the expected format of the constructor:

```
var barvalues = ["myCanvas",data,"yellow",50,0,20,2];

function convertValues(vals) {
  var fields = ['canvasId','data','color','barWidth','minValue','maxValue','gridLineIncrement'];
  var ret = {};
  //TODO check equality of fields.length and vals.length
  //loop through defined fields
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    //set field in object ret
    ret[fields[i]] = vals[i];
  }
  return ret;
}

//call constructor with converted array
new BarChart(convertValues(barvalues));
```

Comment: If you need it even more flexible you can add the `fields` variable as a second parameter to `convertValues`. This would allow to change the order and count of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

After `BarChart` exists, you could shadow it;

```
BarChart = (function (original) { // shadowing IIFE
    function BarChart(p1) { // the new version
        var o = {},
            a = ["canvasId", "data", "color", "barWidth", "minValue", "maxValue", "gridLineIncrement"],
            i;
        if (p1 && p1.constructor === Array) { // if given an array
            for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) { // loop over it
                o[a[i]] = p1[i]; // and set up object
            }
            return original.call(this, o); // then invoke that
        } else { // otherwise
            return original.apply(this, arguments); // invoke as before
        }
    }
    BarChart.prototype = Object.create(original.prototype); // set up inheritance
    return BarChart; // pass out new fn
}(BarChart)); // keep reference to original version
```

---

So what is this new function doing?

1. It's shadowing the old function; this means that new references will all point to this new version instead of the old one, but at the same time it is keeping the old version alive inside itself
2. If an array is given to it, it's assuming you're shorthanding the expected object, and so transforming the array before invoking the old version with it
3. If it's not given an array, it acts transparently
4. When it invokes the old version, is uses `call` or `apply`, so that the `this` is carried over from the new version; meaning that if you used `new` then it gets applied to the instance created with `new`
5. The inheritance is set up such that anything in the *prototype* is carried over, and `instanceof` tests will give the same result as the previous function, meaning the new one is effectively transparent

Why was it made using an *IIFE*? `(function (/* params */) {/* body *}(/* args */));`

- This meant we gained a new *closure* allowing us to keep a reference to the original version of the function even though we were using the same variable name as it

Comment: This I am not complete understanding.? Can you explain in a bit more detail or but up an example on JSFiddle.

Comment: @user3376708 I've added some more explanation

Comment: Can you put my original good in their as well so I can see where this part goes. That is the part that I am not completely seeing.